# what is the appropriate use of h tags

Tags: html

This might sound like a stupid question. But when is it best to use h tags to style content. Look at this code is this appropriate use or should I just use a list to style it.

```
<div class="col-xm-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <h4>Get in touch</h4>
            <h5>Stair World Ltd</h5>
            <h5>Unit K, H & N</h5>
            <h5>The address, Hope Lane,</h5>
            <h5>Halifax, West Yorkshire, HX6 30P</h5>
            <h5>Company Registration Number: 12345767</h5>
            <h5>VAT Registration Number: 899 4178 56</h5>
        </div>
```

Comment: Well... CSS was released like 20 years ago...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when is it best to use h tags to style content

Never.

Use h elements to semantically markup your headings (and subheadings, and sub-subheadings, and so on).

Use CSS to style them.

> Look at this code is this appropriate use

If you wouldn't put the text in your Table Of Contents, then you don't have a heading and shouldn't use an h element.

So no, it isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

That's not appropriate use. `h tags` are mostly used to provide `heading` at starting of section in websites, to give user basic overview of what that section means, so use some other tag, use `span` as below and yes use `CSS` to style them.

```css
span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xm-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <h1>Get in touch</h1>
  <span>Stair World Ltd</span>
  <span>Unit K, H & N </span>
  <span>The address, Hope Lane, </span>
  <span>Halifax, West Yorkshire, HX6 30P </span>
  <span>Company Registration Number: 12345767</span>
  <span>VAT Registration Number: 899 4178 56</span>
</div>
```